# PHP error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$retails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I'm trying get my objects on laravel like this.

But I'm getting this error.

```
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$retails on line 18
```

Also this is my code.

```
public function index(){
        $retails = Auth::user()->companies->retails->all();


        return view('retails/retails', compact('retails'));
    }
```

Company Model

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function retails(){
        $this->hasMany(Retail::class);
    }
}
```

Retail Model

```
class Retail extends Model
{
    public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `companies` and `retails` here...and how they are related

Comment: company has many retail
also retail belongsto company 
And I tried like this but now its giving me this error

Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

$retails = Auth::user()->companies->first()->retails->all();

Comment: can you display your relationship code ?

Comment: @Tiger I updated my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many companies. That is why you get a collection from

`Auth::user()->companies`

When you call `->retails` from the collection instance, you get the exception you wrote.

You have to eager load the companies with retails and then loop through them.

Like:

```
$u = auth()->user();
$u->load('companies.retails');

$userRetails = [];
$u->companies->each(function($company) use (&$userRetails) {
    $userRetails = array_merge($userRetails, $company->retails->toArray());
});

$userRetails = collect($userRetails);
return view('retails/retails', compact('userRetails'));
```

Comment: I'm getting this error @HilmiErdemKEREN

Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: Small fix to the answer: Try `auth()->user()` not `auth()->user`

Comment: In your company class, you forgot to return the relationship. It should be `return $this->hasMany(Retail::class);` not `$this->hasMany(Retail::class);`

Comment: @MuratKaya Not at all. I have also added `->toArray()` to line `$userRetails[] = $company->retails;`. That will give you a simpler collection.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you're trying to access collection from a collection which is impossible, you should individually fetch a collection first and do your process

```
public function index(){
    $companies = Auth::user()->companies;


    foreach($companies as $company) {
        $retails_arr[] = $company->retails;
    }

    $retails = collect($retails_arr); // Gives Collection or
    // Or if you want to send array, try this
    $retails = $retails_arr; // Gives Array


    return view('retails/retails', compact('retails'));
}
```

Try this out hope this helps..

Comment: I tried your code but I'm getting this error

LogicException in Model.php line 2697:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Comment: Looks like there is a `n+1` problem here. I also didn't understand why you converted retails to array.

Comment: Okay I'm trying it @HilmiErdemKEREN

Comment: Now I understood. =)